# Redirect visitor to a different url if a page is accessed more than 5 times?

Tags: php, session, redirect, cookies

I'm trying to redirect a user if they access a page more than 5 times.
So the basic idea is if a user is not logged in on my site and they are browsing a users profile (profile.php) then this counts the number of hits that cookie session has had and redirects to a page to say sign up or something.

I'm new to php and wouldn't know where to start. Could someone please show me.

Comment: dont forget select accept the answer that works best for you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very easy to implement in PHP. Just set a session with the count value and read it after each access.Then you can redirect if the count is 5 or more. Below is a sample code

```
!session_id() ? session_start() : null;
if(!isset($_SESSION['page_access_count'])){
    $_SESSION['page_access_count'] = 1;
}elseif($_SESSION['page_access_count'] >= 5){
    // redirect to signup page
    header('Location:/signup.php');
    exit;
}

    // increase the page access session value
    $_SESSION['page_access_count']++;

    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically you should be able to set a counter in a session variable in server-side or a cookie.
on each visit to the profile page increase that counter. if that counter is greater than `5` then use the php `header` function to redirect the user to your signup page. here is a quick code hint for you using session variable to achieve this:

```
if(! isset($_SESSION["ProfileVisitCount"])){
    $_SESSION["ProfileVisitCount"] = 1;
}

$_SESSION["ProfileVisitCount"]++;

if($_SESSION["ProfileVisitCount"] > 5){
    header("Location: http://domain.com/signup");
    exit();
}
```

Also be sure to start the php session prior to these codes using `session_start()`.

The same thing can be achieved using cookies like this:

```
if(! isset($_COOKIE["ProfileVisitCount"])){
    setcookie("ProfileVisitCount", "1", time()+3600);
}

if($_COOKIE["ProfileVisitCount"] > 5){
    header("Location: http://domain.com/signup");
    exit();
}
else {
    setcookie("ProfileVisitCount", ($_COOKIE["ProfileVisitCount"] + 1), time()+3600);
}
```

### References

- [PHP setcookie() defines a cookie to be sent along with the rest of the HTTP headers.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)
- [PHP sessions basic usage](http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php)
- [PHP header() — Send a raw HTTP header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Answer (score 0):

Use cookies. Here's how I'd do it in PHP:

```
<?php
if (!isset($_COOKIE["cookie1"]))
{
  setcookie(
  "cookie1",
  "1",
  time() + (20 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60),
  '/',
  '.example.com'
);
}
else{
  setcookie(
  "cookie2",
  "2",
  time() + (20 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60),
  '/',
  '.example.com'
);
else{
  setcookie(
  "cookie3",
  "3",
  time() + (20 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60),
  '/',
  '.example.com'
);
}
else{
  setcookie(
  "cookie4",
  "4",
  time() + (20 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60),
  '/',
  '.example.com'
);
}
else{
  setcookie(
  "cookie5",
  "5",
  time() + (20 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60),
  '/',
  '.example.com'
);
}
else
{
header("Location: http://domain.com/signup");
}
}
?>
```

Make sure to replace .example.com with your domain name. And keep the "." instead of "www." if you want it to work when you run it with a domain name with "www", or without it.

Tell me if it works... I can always modify it.

Comment: why setting more than one cookies while one will suffice?

Comment: @Arash Milani It may sound dirty, but it works. It sets a cookie. Next visit, it makes a new one, next visit it makes a new, ect., until the 5th cookie where it redirects. That's my way of counting... probably not the best though... Your method is much better :P