# Redirect visitors to different urls (depending on how many times have they visited the page)

Tags: php, redirect, cookies

I hope you are doing well!
Im wondering how to redirect users to different pages who have visited my page for the 1st time... 2nd, 3rd, 5th using cookie based script.

For ex.
Users enters my website for the 1-st time:
Redirecting to page page1.com

Users enters my website for the second time:
Redirecting to page page2.com

3 times:
Redirecting to page page3.com

5 times
Redirecting to page page4.com

etc.

I have found similar code here: [Redirect visitor to a different url if a page is accessed more than 5 times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14016674/redirect-visitor-to-a-different-url-if-a-page-is-accessed-more-than-5-times) but because I'm php newbie I'm not sure how to add redirects to different numbers of visits, including 1-st

```
    if(! isset($_COOKIE["ProfileVisitCount"])){
    setcookie("ProfileVisitCount", "1", time()+3600);
}

if($_COOKIE["ProfileVisitCount"] > 5){
    header("Location: http://domain.com/signup");
    exit();
}
else {
    setcookie("ProfileVisitCount", ($_COOKIE["ProfileVisitCount"] + 1), time()+3600);
}
```

I would be really appreciated for any help!
Thanks

Comment: you have to increment $_COOKIE["ProfileVisitCount"] values

Comment: Could use a switch statement with the value of the $_COOKIE["ProfileVisitCount"]

Comment: check my answer , if each time you have to increment counter value when user visit your site .

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like that.

```
if(! isset($_COOKIE["ProfileVisitCount"])){
    setcookie("ProfileVisitCount", "1", time()+3600);
}else{
    if($_COOKIE["ProfileVisitCount"] > 5){
        header("Location: http://domain.com/signup");
       exit();
    }else{
        $count = $_COOKIE["ProfileVisitCount"] +1;
      setcookie('ProfileVisitCount', $count, time()+3600, "/");
    }
}
else {
    setcookie("ProfileVisitCount", ($_COOKIE["ProfileVisitCount"] + 1), time()+3600);
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply, but to be honest I still don't know how to redirect users who have visited my page for the 1-st, 3rd, 5th time etc. This script just looks similar to the one is posted. Im wondering how to do something like this. `if($_COOKIE["ProfileVisitCount"] < 2){ header("Location: page1.com"); }, if($_COOKIE["ProfileVisitCount"] >= 3){ header("Location: page2.com"); },if($_COOKIE["ProfileVisitCount"] >= 5){ header("Location: page3.com"); }`. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try something like this:
replace "Location: page1.com"
echo "<script type='text/javascript'> document.location = 'http://page1.com'; </script>";